# Mixing two audio samples from MP3 files

Tags: c#, audio

I am having problem mixing two different audio samples into one by simply adding the bytes of both audio samples.

After below process when I try to open mixed.mp3 file in media player it says:

> Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing the file.

Here is the code I'm using to mix the audio files:

```
byte[] bytes1,bytes2,final;
int length1,length2,max;

// Getting byte[] of audio file
using ( BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("background.mp3" , FileMode.Open)) )
{
    length1 = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
    bytes1 = b.ReadBytes(length1);
}

using ( BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("voice.mp3" , FileMode.Open)) )
{
    length2 = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
    bytes2 = b.ReadBytes(length2);
}

// Getting max length
if(length1 > length2){
    max = length1;
}else{
    max = length2;
}

// Initializing output byte[] of max length
final = new byte[max];

// Adding byte1 and byte2 and copying into final
for (int i=0;i<max;i++)
{
    byte b1 , b2;

    if(i < length1){
        b1 = bytes1[i];
    }else{
        b1 = 0;
    }

    if ( i < length2 ){
        b2 = bytes2[i];
    }
    else{
        b2 = 0;
    }

    final[i] = (byte)(b1 + b2);
}

// Writing final[] as an mp3 file
File.WriteAllBytes("mixed.mp3" , final);
```

Note: I tried to mix two same files and it worked, that is, the media player didn't throw any errors and played it correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by your bottom note? You mean the code works now?

Comment: This is not possible. Mp3 is not row wave data. Adding bytes just like that will 100% corrupt data.not sure how it worked for you

Comment: Decode it, do your calculations, keep the crop in mind (0..255), encode it again. What you do right now cannot work because: mp3 is compressed (unless it just contains amplitude data.. am no expert there), also you got to consider the header with all the metadata that you should not change when working on the file level.

Comment: @TaLha Khan does my answer work for you or not?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman no. your answer is same as what i am doing, i mean just appending bytes.

Comment: My mediaplayer works fine with this method doe.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman it will work with exact same mp3 files but not with different.

Comment: Oh thanks for teh info :)

Comment: The audio samples in MP3 files usually aren't even single bytes!  What steps are you taking to convert the MP3 format into actual audio data?

Answer (score 10):

This is mostly likely due to the fact that you aren't [decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_codec) the MP3 files *before* you mix them. *And* you're "just adding" the samples together, which is going to result in [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(audio)); you should first use a [library](https://naudio.codeplex.com/) to decode the MP3 files to PCM, which will then allow you to mix them.

To correctly mix the samples you should be doing:

```
final[i] = (byte)(b1 / 2 + b2 / 2);
```

Otherwise your calculations will overflow (also, I'd generally recommend normalising your audio to `float`s before manipulating them). It should also be noted that you're mixing *all* the bytes in the MP3 files, i.e., you're messing with the headers (hence WMP refusing to play your "Mixed" file). You should only mix the actual audio data (the samples) of the files, not the entire file.

I've provided a (commented) working example<sup>1</sup> using the NAudio library (it exports the mixed audio to a wav file to avoid further complications):

```
// You can get the library via NuGet if preferred.
using NAudio.Wave;

...

var fileA = new AudioFileReader("Input path 1");

// Calculate our buffer size, since we're normalizing our samples to floats
// we'll need to account for that by dividing the file's audio byte count
// by its bit depth / 8.
var bufferA = new float[fileA.Length / (fileA.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8)];

// Now let's populate our buffer with samples.
fileA.Read(bufferA, 0, bufferA.Length);

// Do it all over again for the other file.
var fileB = new AudioFileReader("Input path 2");
var bufferB = new float[fileB.Length / (fileB.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8)];
fileB.Read(bufferB, 0, bufferB.Length);

// Calculate the largest file (simpler than using an 'if').
var maxLen = (long)Math.Max(bufferA.Length, bufferB.Length);
var final = new byte[maxLen];

// For now, we'll just save our mixed data to a wav file.
// (Things can get a little complicated when encoding to MP3.)
using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter("Output path", fileA.WaveFormat))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++)
    {
        float a, b;

        if (i < bufferA.Length)
        {
            // Reduce the amplitude of the sample by 2
            // to avoid clipping.
            a = bufferA[i] / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            a = 0;
        }

        if (i < bufferB.Length)
        {
            b = bufferB[i] / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            b = 0;
        }

        writer.WriteSample(a + b);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The input files must be of the same sample rate, bit depth and channel count in order for it to work correctly.